# Difference between plain go func and for loop in go func

Tags: go, channel, goroutine

I have some question regarding difference between plain go func and for loop in go func:

1. Plain go Func:

   ```
   func asyncTask(){
       //...something
   }
   ```

   in order to trigger asyncTask, we can simply:

   ```
   func main(){
       go asyncTask()
   }
   ```
2. make a for loop to monitor channel:

   ```
   func (c *Container) asyncTask(){
       go func(){
           for {
               select {
                   case <- c.someChan:
                       //...do something
                   case <-c.ctx.Done():
                       //...prevent leaking
               }
           }
       }()
   }
   ```

   to trigger:

   ```
   func (c *Container) trigger(){
       c.someChan <- val
   }
   ```

My questions are:

1. I understand second scenario most fit the case when we wish to manage async task in a queue.
   But speaking for performance out of frequently triggered async task (which cannot be block), which method is better?
2. Is there any best practice in general to handle async task in GoLang?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use model #1 with WaitGroups when you have goroutines for which you need to account for and are bothered only about their exit and as such otherwise don't need to manage etc.

You can use model #2 when you need explicit management / control / communication. Channel communication is NOT free - sending and receiving routines need synchronization/channels need locking when values are sent, lot of things will have to happen under the hood.

Unless the need be, definitely option #1 is the way to go. See what's the simplest possible solution for your problem - I know it's easy to preach, but simplicity may take some time to come by.

Answer (score 4):

In nearly any case, performance is not the thing to think about in choosing which pattern to use (both will be fine), but which usage makes sense in your specific use case. If you use pattern (1), then you are not guaranteed the sequential processing of (2). That is the essential difference between your two examples. So for an http server for example, you would use the former pattern (`go handleRequest(r HttpRequest)` say) to process requests in parallel, but use the latter to ensure that certain operations are processed sequentially. I hope this is answering your question!

Answer (score 1):

In short, from that what i know, 2 pattern you mentioned above is not something to really compare which one to use or which one is better. Both of them just have different use case with different necessity.

**From what i know, it is not about**

> plain go func and for loop in go func

It is more to different usage.

Before answering your question, i like to try give short explanation about two pattern you mentioned.

1. The first pattern is a very basic `go` statement usage. Which just will execute function outside its main thread. As **basic** usage of concurrency in go, this pattern design doesn't have a way to get data from executed function with `go` statement. Can't be from `main()` thread or any other function. In order to **communicate** with any other function / thread its needs `channel`. You already mention **one** pattern form several `go` with `channel` pattern available.
2. Just like what i mentioned earlier, this second pattern is just one of several `go` with `channel` pattern in Golang in usage with `go` statement. Actually this one is quite complex pattern which main usage is for **selecting from multiple channels** and will do further things with those channels. I will give some slight explanation about this pattern as folow:

   - The `for` loop there has no conditional statement which will work similarly like `while` loop at any other language like C or Java. It is mean an endless loop.
   - Since it is endless loop, it is need a condition which usually check from the available channels to check. For example, something like when a channel is closed it will be end.
   - Regarding `select` and `case` statement, if two or more communication cases happen to be ready at the same time, one will be selected at random
   - Even you need to communicate between concurrent/asynchronous functions running, i guess you not need it in general. Generally there is more simple pattern to communicate the threads by using channel.

**In summary to answer your questions:**

1. Which method is better to do asynchronous task is really depend on your necessity. There are several pattern which not limited to you have mentioned above. If you need just do execute function asynchronously first pattern will be fine otherwise you need one from `channel` pattern way available. But again, not limited to 2nd pattern you mentioned above
2. Both pattern you mentioned looks as common practices for me. But i guess usually we often need at least a `channel` in order to communicate an asynchronous task with `main()` thread or any other thread. And the pattern it self really depend on how you will communicate (send/receive) the data/values sources (Database, slices variables etc.) and more other aspect. I suggest you learn more about the usage of `channel` there are lot patterns to do with that. I suggest to check this first https://gobyexample.com/goroutines. Start from there you see at the bottom of page the "Next Example" which will getting deeper about go concurrency things.

**As addition:**

`go` statement is simple, the complex things is about the usage with `channel`. Here is i make list you better to learn in order to have better understanding about concurrency communication.

- goroutine
- Channel direction ( Send / Receive / unidirectional )
- Channel concept / behavior which is **communicating sequential
  processes (CSP)** . It is some kind about "block" and "proceed" behavior of send/receive behavior.
- Buffered channel
- Unbuffered channel
- And more about channel :)

Hope this helps you or some one to start with goroutine and channel to works with concurrency in Golang. Please feel free if some one like to give corrections to my answer or ask further explanation about it. Thank you.